# Create new array with deducted values of another array's elements - JS

Tags: javascript

I need to create an array that has same number of elements, but the values should deducted. Example:

Initial array:

```
myArray = [1, 3, 6, 7, 11, 14]
```

New array:

```
newArray = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3]
```

So 1 - 0, 3 - 1, 6 - 3 etc... Any advice on how to achieve this?

Comment: What have you done? Show your code so people can see what's wrong with it and fix your problem.

Comment: I assume you mean 1-1, 3-2, 6-3, 7-1... Since the numbers you gave aren't in the example

Comment: Please share the code you tried so far. We should not expect readymade answers on this forum.

Comment: `newArray  = myArray.map((v,i) => i===0 ? v : v - myArray[i-1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
myArray = [1, 3, 6, 7, 11, 14];
var i = 0;
console.log(myArray.map(e => {
  var k = e - i;
  i = e;
  return k
}))
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
const myArray = [1, 3, 6, 7, 11, 14];
const newArray = [];

for(let i = 0;i<myArray.length; i++) {
  if(myArray[i+1] !== undefined) {
  newArray.push(myArray[i+1]-myArray[i]);

  }
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map` like this:

```js
let myArray = [1, 3, 6, 7, 11, 14];
let newArray = myArray.map((element, index, myArray) => 
    element - (myArray[index - 1] || 0));
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
const myArray = [1, 3, 6, 7, 11, 14];

const newArray = Array.from({
  length: myArray.length
}, (_, i) => {
  return myArray[i - 1] ? myArray[i] - myArray[i - 1] : myArray[i]
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to put 2 arrays together or want an array of current/next or as in your case current/previous you can use zip:

```js
const zip = (a, b) =>
  a.map((item, index) => [
    item,
    b[index],
  ]);

const myArray = [1, 3, 6, 7, 11, 14];

console.log(
  zip(myArray, [0].concat(myArray))//[[current,previous],...][[1,0],[3,1],[6,3]...]
  .map(
    ([a, b]) => a - b,
  ),
);
```